# unexpected call of useState in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to save current and previous states of a component, so I created 2 variables `advertisersPriorities` and `oldPriorities`
Firstly, I fetch data from a server (using fuction `getPriorities`), and then update it according to user input via `Autocomplete` from `"@mui/material"`

When a value in autocompelte is changed, I update an `advertisersPriorities` state, but `oldPriorities` also updates, even though I do not call a connected fuction to update it.

if I remove `oldPriorities`, then updating from `getPriorities` everything starts working fine...

Could you please clarify, why does this happening?

A code related to the issue is listed below:

```
const [oldPriorities, setOldPriorities] = useState([])
const [advertisersPriorities, setAdvertisersPriorities] = useState([])

async function getPriorities(store: StoreRecord){
    const prioritiesData =  await getData("stores/"+ store.id + "/priorities") //fetching data from a server
    ... //processing rhis data and saving in both new and old states and placing it to newPrioritesList variable
    setAdvertisersPriorities([...newPrioritesList])
    setOldPriorities([...newPrioritesList])
}

//this function updates the current state called advertisersPriorities
function setAdvertiserPriority(newPriority: string, index: number) {
    let newWeights = advertisersPriorities
    newWeights[index].priority = newPriority
    setAdvertisersPriorities([...newWeights])
    updateEquilibriumTable()
}

function updateEquilibriumTable() {
    console.log('oldPriorities', oldPriorities)
}

return (
...
 <MDButton variant="gradient" color="dark" size="large" onClick={() =>{getPriorities(targetStore)}}>
                        Select
 </MDButton>    
 <Autocomplete
    value={row.priority}
    onChange={(event: any, newValue: string) => {
      setAdvertiserPriority(newValue, row.index);
    }}
    sx={{width: 150, mr: 0}}
    options={priorityOptions}
    renderInput={(params) => <FormField {...params} InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />}
  />

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens, it is usually because both arrays contains references to same objects.

Please try to replace `setOldPriorities([...newPrioritesList])` with this:

```
setOldPriorities(newPrioritesList.map(it => ({...it})))
```

The above code will create an array of cloned elements from `newPrioritesList`.